# Delete csv files having less than 10 entries from a particular directory in R

Tags: r, csv

I have around 100 csv files in a particular directory and I want to use moving average forecast for all files. Following is the code I have written:

```
fileNames <- Sys.glob("*.csv")
for (fileName in fileNames) {      
  abc <- read.csv(fileName, header = TRUE, sep = ",")

  library(stats)
  library(graphics)
  library(forecast)
  library(TTR)
  library(zoo)
  library(tseries)

  abc1 = abc[,1]
  abc1 = t(t(abc1))
  abc1 = as.vector(abc1)

  abc2 = ts(abc1, frequency = 12,start = c(2014,1))
  abc_decompose = decompose(abc2)
  plot(abc_decompose)

  forecast = (abc_decompose$trend)
  x <- data.frame(abc, forecast)
  write.csv (x, file = fileName, row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE)
}
```

Now this code is working perfectly. It's appending a column called forecast to each of the csv files and writing the forecast values in them. The problem is among those 100 csv files some are too small and R is showing following error:
`Error in decompose(abc2) : time series has no or less than 2 periods`

Actually I'm not interested in files having less than 10 entries but deleting those manually is difficult. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can count the rows of each csv file inside your `for` loop

```
nrows <- sapply( csvfile, function(f) nrow(read.csv(f)) )
```

And then do what you do if nrows>10.
In order to delete those files use [unlink](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/unlink.html).

```
unlink(x, recursive = FALSE, force = FALSE)
```

Comment: Note: if you don't want to delete the original files, but simply don't want to process then, just use something like `if(nrows<10) break` inside your loop.

Comment: `nrows` is giving me the no. of rows for each of the csv files, but when I'm using `if(nrows<10) break` or, `if (nrows>10){#my desired operations}` R is giving the following warning message: `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` and the program is not giving the desired output.

Comment: In case I don't use any restriction about no. of rows and run the code over all csv files in that directory, R is showing me the following error `Error in decompose(abc2) : time series has no or less than 2 periods`